# WAMP data compare script taking very long

Tags: php, mysql, compare

I'm running a comparison of some data using PHP to access MySQL tables. The script takes well over an hour to run. We're dealing with about 100k rows in the source data and 300k in each of the target tables, i.e. two tables.

There's no more than 10 columns total in each table.

Here is the script:

```
$query = "SELECT bbva_check_deductions.empno, bbva_check_deductions.idr, bbva_check_deductions.current1, bbva_job.paygroup 
            FROM bbva_check_deductions 
            LEFT JOIN bbva_job 
            ON bbva_check_deductions.empno = bbva_job.file_nbr 
            ORDER BY current1 DESC, EmpNo DESC, IDR DESC";
    $result_set = mysql_query($query,$connection);

    while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set)) {
        $emplid = compare_filter($result['empno']);
        $oldCode = compare_filter($result['idr']);
        $origCode = $oldCode;
        $payGroup = compare_filter($result['paygroup']);

        $codes = array('DC6', 'HTH', 'DM4', '4UP', 'DC1', 'DC3', 'DC4', 'DEN', 'DCR', 'MDR', 'PRK', 'VIS', '41K');

        //CALCULATE WEEK NO
        if ($payGroup == "J2C") {$week = 24;}
        elseif ($payGroup == "J2E") {$week = 26;}
        else {$week = 22;}

        //QUERY TRANSLATION TABLE FOR TRANSLATED VALUE
        $translate_query = "SELECT * FROM translation WHERE sourceValue = '{$oldCode}' 
        AND sourceField LIKE '%ded_code%' LIMIT 1";
        $translate_result_set = mysql_query($translate_query, $connection); 
        if (mysql_num_rows($translate_result_set) > 0) {
            $translate_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($translate_result_set);
            $oldCode = compare_filter($translate_result['translatedValue']);
        }

        //DETERMINE IF MEMO
        if ($oldCode == "GTL" || $oldCode == "BLI" || $oldCode == "BLT" || $oldCode == "HIC" || $oldCode == "DM4") {
            $queryField = "memo_code"; $queryTable = "pf_check_memo";
        } else {
            $queryField = "deduction_code"; $queryTable = "pf_check_deductions";
        }

        $compare_query = "SELECT {$queryField}, amount_field_for_payroll 
                        FROM {$queryTable} 
                        WHERE empl_id = {$emplid} 
                        AND {$queryField} LIKE '%{$oldCode}%' 
                        AND week_number = {$week} 
                        LIMIT 1";
        $compare_result_set = mysql_query($compare_query, $connection);

        if (mysql_num_rows($compare_result_set) != 0) {
            $compare_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($compare_result_set);
            //PREP COMPARE FIELDS
            $amount = compare_filter($result['current1']);
            $compare_amount = compare_filter($compare_result['amount_field_for_payroll']);

            $negCodes = array('DC6', 'HTH', 'DM4', '4UP', 'DC1', 'DC3', 'DC4', 'DEN', 'DCR', 'MDR', 'PRK', 'VIS', '41K');
            if (in_array($oldCode,$negCodes)) {$compare_amount = $compare_amount * -1;}

            //AMOUNT COMPARE
            direct_compare_basic($amount,$compare_amount,"amount","bbva_check_deductions","Y",$origCode,$oldCode);

        }   else {$content .= $emplid . $separator . "" . $separator . "Emplid + Deduction Code + Pay Group" . $separator . 'bbva_check_deductions' . 
                $separator . field_prep($emplid . " - " . $oldCode . " - " . $payGroup) . $separator . "No Record Found in PF for week {$week}" . $separator . "Y" . $separator . "Y" . 
                $separator . $origCode . $separator . $oldCode . $break;}
```

Then it just writes to a .CSV file.

My functions do not call any additional queries, just formatting stuff. I'm running InnoDB tables and have indexes for all columns being used. My PC is running WAMP, it's got 16G of RAM and a quad core processor. The HDD is 7200 RPM.

Seems like it is taking far too long to me. Any ideas?

Comment: Looking briefly at this, you have a query inside the result loop of another query. That can't possibly be the only option?

Comment: Do you have access to the mysql console or something like mysqladmin? You should run `EXPLAIN` on your query (just put `explain` in front of it). I think on your first query you'll see that `LEFT JOIN` and especially `ORDER BY` are really slow. You likely need to add more indexes to your table.

Comment: The calculations behind the scenes are pretty complex, its the only good option I have (that i know of). I will try the EXPLAIN clause. I should have mentioned, i have an index for all of the columns im querying.

Comment: The top query itself only takes about half a second to run. Its obviously the nested query that is the issue, however ive run similar scripts on previous systems that never took this long (on comparable tables)